# Angular2 how to update image in another component

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am having two components one is of top-bar and another for profile management page.

The issue is on updating the profile image it should also get changed from top-bar header also. It does but on page reload. I want it to be on instant.

For this I can do this if I hit a function in top-bar component and alter variable that shows image. But I am unable to figure out that how I can do so I mean if image is updated in a my-profile component then how I can call a function of top-bar component and change the value of variable.

What I tried is:

**top-bar.component.ts :**

```
@Component({


selector: 'top-bar',
  templateUrl: './top-bar.component.html',
})
export class TopBarComponent {
     @Output() myEvent = new EventEmitter();
       test()
    {
    console.log("in test");
    }
   }
```

**my-profile.component.html:**

```
<top-bar #modal></top-bar>
    <top-bar (myEvent)="modal.test()"></top-bar>
```

I am expecting that on my-profile page load I should get console.log("in tets");. Please correct me if wrong and how can i achieve so. Thanks in

I have imported top-bar component in my-profile component already

Comment: I would use the service which can watching the event on image changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have an image element in your top bar component. You will need to create an input for that component which you will use to bind the image to.

So somewhere in your class you will do this.

```
export class TopBarComponent {
    @Input() imageSrc: string;
}
```

Which you will use in your template like so

```
<img [src]="imageSrc"></img>
```

Comment: Thanks i think your solution is perfect but can you please tell me how I can pass value in imageSrc form my my-profile component. Thanks in advance

Comment: @NarendraVyas you can get to know about that [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html)

Comment: I am getting Can't bind to 'imageSrc' since it isn't a known property of 'child' as both are seperate component and top-bar is not child of my-profile.

Comment: So where are you binding this ?

Comment: actually i have one parent dashboard which has two child top-bar and my-profile. I have imported top-bar in my-profile

Comment: @NarendraVyas Well you would need to show me more code of your profile component, you will probably have to define a class member with the source of your image and use the topBarComponent like so
`<top-bar [imageSrc]="imageFromParentComponentSrc"></top-bar>`

Comment: Hi Abdel: Thanks the solution worked for me, but i am getting an issue that my links in sidebar got changed now I think that my-profile has set as root. Do you have any idea.

Comment: @Abdel: Thanks I resolved all issues. again thanks for best advise

Comment: @NarendraVyas Glad I could help you sir!

Comment: :), just one thing if you can help me actually how to set default value in this.

Comment: For any input you could do something like this `@Input() myFancyInput: string = 'myDef value'`

Comment: I am using @Input() imageSrc: string= localStorage.getItem('profile_image'); . Now issue is this works only once as image is changed in imageSrc var its scope seems to be till that page only as both are different component so again in local storage I get previous value only not updated value

Comment: I mean its default value is set correctly but after changing image it doesnt set for all pages.

Answer (score 2):

Here are working [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/IYaM5Izgsaqw7DjCk9X8?p=preview) components.. This may help you, here header image get changed with/from profile component

**Header Component:**

```
@Component({
             selector: 'app-header',
             template: `<header>
                       <img [src]="imgSrc"> 
                       <app-profile (reloadParent)="setImage($event)" 
                       [imgUrl]="imgSrc"></app-profile>
                       </header>`
      })
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
   imgSrc;
   constructor() { }
   ngOnInit() {
   this.setImage({src: "http://files.softicons.com/download/system-
                 icons/oxygen-icons-by-
   oxygen/png/128x128/actions/format_font_size_less.png"});
 }
  setImage($event){
  this.imgSrc = $event.src;
  }
}
```

**Profile Component**

```
@Component({
           selector: 'app-profile',
           template: `<div id="">
           <img [src]="imgUrl">
           <button (click)="changeImage()">Change Image</button>
           </div>`
   })
  export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() imgUrl: string;
  @Output() reloadParent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {     }
  changeImage(){
       var img = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?
        q=tbn:ANd9GcQWVbaiDV_SRbWJJVfyn7wOinekRzs9xiCHdZK5RU86bkICXcaz";
        this.reloadParent.emit({src: img });
     }
  }
```